# Multiple thmboxes with for each loop

Tags: environments, foreach, loops, preamble, thmbox

I want to get rid of a lot of redundant code while defining thmxboxes. I tried to use for-each loops, but it does not work. The following code (that does not work) should give you an idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{thmtools} % boxes
\usepackage{pgffor} % for-Schleifen

\foreach \x in {Definition, Axiom}{
    \foreach \y in {definition, axiom}{
        \declaretheorem[thmbox=M, within = section,]{\x}%
        \newenvironment{\y}[1][]{%
            \begin{\x}%
            % ... here may be more code
            \normalfont%
        }%
        {\end{\x}}
    }
}

% This works, but creates lots of redundant code
%\declaretheorem[thmbox=M, within = section,]{Definition}%
%       \newenvironment{definition}[1][]{%
%           \begin{Definition}%
            % ... here may be more code
%           \normalfont%
        }%
%       {\end{Definition}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{definition}[titel]
        Ceterum censeo Carthaginem esse delendam.
    \end{definition}
\end{document}
```

Without the `\foreach` (and changing \x and \y) the code works (but creates lots of redundant code). I hope I was able to explain my problem and someone can help me!

Comment: the pgf for loop puts each iteration in a group so it is of limited use in programming constructs. Most loop macros don't do that eg `\loop` or `\@for` or ...

Comment: I'm new to advanced LaTeX programming, therefore I don't understand what macros I could use for that. Can you give me an example solution for my problem using the correct macros?

Comment: well I don't actually understand what you want, `\foreach \x in {Definition, Axiom}{   \foreach \y in {definition, axiom}{`   is 4 iterations,  so you want to define the `definition` environment twice, once with `Definition` in the inner call and once with `Axiom` ? what is the scope of these two definitions? Similarly you define `axiom` twice once with `Definition` and once with `Axiom` ?

Comment: I see what you mean. Yes this is a mistake. I only want 2 Iterations, one with Definition and definition, one with Axiom and axiom.... I didn't saw it till u mentioned it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can understand the intention, you don't really want a loop at all just a specific declaration generator, something like:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{thmtools} % boxes


\newcommand\mythm[3]{%
        \declaretheorem[thmbox=M, within = section,]{#1}%
        \newenvironment{#2}[1][]{%
            \begin{#1}[##1]%
            #3%
            \normalfont%
        }%
        {\end{#1}}%
}

\mythm{Definition}{definition}{}
\mythm{Axiom}{axiom}{}




\begin{document}
    \begin{definition}[titel]
        Ceterum censeo Carthaginem esse delendam.
    \end{definition}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow thank you for the answer. That's a good idea. But how do I use the option of new environment?

Comment: @Titanlord it depends what you want to do with it, I just copied your definition. If you want to pass it on to the inner environment then `\begin{#1}[##1]%`  instead of `\begin{#1}%` probably does what you want.

Comment: @Titanlord I added that to the code above

Comment: Yes that was exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much!